# Java post-increment and pre increment behaviour

Tags: java, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

I have a simple Java expression depicted below. Based on [Operator Precedence table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), I expect that this expression would return division by zero exception (since post-fix increment operator has highest priority) and expect that resulting expression would look like:

```
2 + 2 + 5 / 0
```

But result is 7, why ? (By little bit of experimentation I found that all operators are assigned value of 1 for some reason, but this does not make sense to me in case priority table is correct)

```
int intCountOperator = 0;
unaryOperand = ++intCountOperator + intCountOperator + 5 / intCountOperator++;
System.out.println(unaryOperand); // Prints 7
```

Comment: It's because of left-to-right evaluation order, which is orthogonal to operator precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator precedence does not control the evaluation order. It controls only how the expression is to be read. For example, since multiplication has a higher precedence than addition, `x + y * z` is read as `x + (y * z)`, not `(x + y) * z`. However, it does not change that first `x` is evaluated, then `y` and finally `z`.

Giving a good example with `++` and `--` is more difficult, because there is usually only one reading which makes sense. However, you might notice that `y - x++` compiles without error (if `x` and `y` are numerical variables). If `++` would have had a lower precedence than `-` it would be evaluated as `(x - y)++` which would not compile.

Because of operator precedence, your expression is evaluated as:

```
(++intCountOperator) + (intCountOperator + (5 / (intCountOperator++)));
```

but the evaluation order is not changed by it.

Answer (score 2):

The expression is evaluated from left to right :

```
unaryOperand = ++intCountOperator + intCountOperator + 5 / intCountOperator++;
                        1         +          1       + 5 / 1                    = 7
```

Note that the operators are evaluated in the order you expect, i.e. `1 + 1 + (5/1) = 1 + 1 + 5 = 7`, but the operands of all those expressions are evaluated from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

The order of evaluation is from left to right and not right to left. So the result 7 which you are getting is correct.

```
unaryOperand = ++intCountOperator + intCountOperator + 5 / intCountOperator++;
```

is actually

```
unaryOperand = 1 + 1 + 5 / 1; = 7
```

Comment: Thanks, however I'm a bit surprised then, expected that highest priority operators are evaluated first. Like when I evaluate 5 + 6 / 3 it first evaluates division, then addition (because of priority)

Comment: Java *always* evaluates operands left-to-right. Operator precedence tells you the order in which those operands are subsequently combined.

Comment: In te latter it first evaluates 5/1 then thé additions So wbat is the problème. Thé only thing thats changes is thé évaluation of PREfixe operator which has a higher priorité in ghe table anyways.